# MySQL - UPDATE one table with columns transposed from another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a problem updating a table with columns transposed from another table. I investigated here and got close to the solution, but still I do not hit the point.

I have a table `tbl_g08t1` with the following columns along with others not included for brevity (1st row : column names):

```
shl62 carrno    typ stat    50      71      72      73      74      75      76
747  35712528   0   6       29  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)
747  35722615   0   6       29  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)
747  35722625   0   6       29  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)
747  35722664   0   6       29  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)
821  35136730   0   8     (NULL)(NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)
821  35722678   0   8       29  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)
821  35833255   0   6     (NULL)(NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)
```

I have a second table `tbl_s80t1` with freetexts, it looks like:

```
sysfromt    sysshort freecode freetext
G08T1       35722652    98      101
G08T1       35722652    132     KCF9F27                                                               
G08T1       35722664    50      29
G08T1       35722664    71      20171004
G08T1       35722664    74      01Y                                                                   
G08T1       35722664    75      3
G08T1       35722664    76      A17108176                                                             
G08T1       35722664    97      8397080
G08T1       35722664    98      101
G08T1       35722664    132     KCF9F13                                                               
G08T1       35722678    50      29
G08T1       35722678    71      20171005
G08T1       35722678    74      01Y                                                                   
G08T1       35722678    75      3
G08T1       35722678    76      D1718496                                                              
G08T1       35722678    97      8395896
G08T1       35722678    98      101
G08T1       35722678    132     KCF9F27                                                               
G08T1       35722684    8       2017-10-05 09:53 C:3 Out:9 General fault!                             
G08T1       35722684    8       2017-10-05 09:54 C:3 Out:9 General fault!                             
G08T1       35722684    50      29
```

I am trying to merge the two tables with

```
`tbl_g08t1`.`carrno` = `tbl_s80t1`.`sysshort` AND `tbl_s80t1`.`sysfromt` = 'G08T1'
```

and transposing some rows of the second one according to the `freecode`, I ended up with the following code :

```
USE general_db;
    UPDATE tbl_g08t1
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_s80t1` ON (`tbl_g08t1`.`carrno` = `tbl_s80t1`.`sysshort` AND
              `tbl_s80t1`.`sysfromt` = 'G08T1')
      SET
         `50` = (SELECT MAX(`tbl_s80t1`.`freetext`) WHERE `tbl_s80t1`.`freecode` = 50),
         `71` = (SELECT MAX(`tbl_s80t1`.`freetext`) WHERE `tbl_s80t1`.`freecode` = 72),
         `72` = (SELECT MAX(`tbl_s80t1`.`freetext`) WHERE `tbl_s80t1`.`freecode` = 73),
         `76` = (SELECT MAX(`tbl_s80t1`.`freetext`) WHERE `tbl_s80t1`.`freecode` = 76)
```

The problem is that only one column `50` is updated, all other `71...76` have all (NULL) value. I expected to have `freetext` values there, of course where the `freecode` value is relevant.

Well, I don't know if I have been clear...or made more confusion..
Thanks for any hint.

Ema

PS
when running the query I get the message

```
33278 row(s) affected, 64 warning(s): 1265 Data truncated for column '50' at row 1
```

Comment: Are the columns 50-76 Varchar or int?

Comment: They are all Varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your set clauses. Using MAX() and SELECT is a sub-query, and doesn't refer to the JOIN clause. They are independent from that. I think this might work:

```
USE general_db;
UPDATE tbl_g08t1
    SET
     `50` = (SELECT MAX(`tbl_s80t1`.`freetext`) FROM tbl_s80t1 WHERE `tbl_s80t1`.`freecode` = 50 AND `tbl_g08t1`.`carrno` = `tbl_s80t1`.`sysshort` AND `tbl_s80t1`.`sysfromt` = 'G08T1')),
     `71` = (SELECT MAX(`tbl_s80t1`.`freetext`) FROM tbl_s80t1 WHERE `tbl_s80t1`.`freecode` = 71 AND `tbl_g08t1`.`carrno` = `tbl_s80t1`.`sysshort` AND `tbl_s80t1`.`sysfromt` = 'G08T1')),
     `72` = (SELECT MAX(`tbl_s80t1`.`freetext`) FROM tbl_s80t1 WHERE `tbl_s80t1`.`freecode` = 73 AND `tbl_g08t1`.`carrno` = `tbl_s80t1`.`sysshort` AND `tbl_s80t1`.`sysfromt` = 'G08T1')),
     `76` = (SELECT MAX(`tbl_s80t1`.`freetext`) FROM tbl_s80t1 WHERE `tbl_s80t1`.`freecode` = 76 AND `tbl_g08t1`.`carrno` = `tbl_s80t1`.`sysshort` AND `tbl_s80t1`.`sysfromt` = 'G08T1'))
```

Without a SQL Fiddle, I can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! It works! I just had to change the lenght of the columns `50...76` from VARCHAR 50 to 255. There is just one extra ")" at the end of each statements to be removed.
Execution time is pretty good: 15 secs to  update > 3 millions records.